# difference between async.series and async.parallel

Tags: node.js

What is the difference between async.series and async.parallel. Consider the following exmaple, and i've got the same result.

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 'one');
        }, 200);
    },
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 'two');
        }, 100);
    },
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            var err = new Error('I am the error');
            callback(err);
        }, 400);
    },
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 'three');
        }, 600);
    },
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
    if(err){
        console.log('Error');
    } else {

    }
    console.log(results);
    //results is now equal to [ 'one', 'two', undefined ]
    // the second function had a shorter timeout.
});
```

and

```
async.series([
   function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 'one');
        }, 200);
    },
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 'two');
        }, 100);
    },
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            var err = new Error('I am the error');
            callback(err);
        }, 400);
    },
    function(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
            callback(null, 'three');
        }, 600);
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
    //results is now equal to [ 'one', 'two', undefined ]
    if(err){
        console.log('Error');
    } else {

    }
    console.log(results);
});
```

i don't see the difference. Maybe is my sample bad? I read the documentation about these two function on github async repository, you can find for async.parallel function:

> If any of the functions pass an error to its callback, the main
>   callback is immediately called with the value of the error

what is the main callback in async.parallel?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`async.series` invokes your functions serially (waiting for each preceding one to finish before starting next). `async.parallel` will launch them all simultaneously (or whatever passes for simultaneous in one-thread land, anyway).

The main callback is the one optionally supplied in the call to `async.parallel` or `async.series` (The signature is `async.parallel(tasks, [callback])`)

So what actually happens is this:

### parallel:

- `parallel` launches all the tasks, then waits
- all four tasks schedule their timeouts
- timeout 100 fires, adds its result (result is now `[ , "Two"]`)
- timeout 200 fires, adds its result (result is now `["One", "Two"]`)
- timeout 400 fires, returns error and `undefined` as result (result is now `["One", "Two", undefined]`)
- `parallel` notices an error, immediately returns the result it received so far
- timeout 600 fires, but no-one cares about the return result

### series:

- `series` fires the first task; it schedules its timeout.
- `series` waits till callback is called 200ms later, then adds the result. (result is now `["One"]`)
- `series` fires the second task; it schedules its timeout.
- `series` waits till callback is called 100ms later, then adds the result. (result is now `["One", "Two"]`)
- `series` fires the third task; it schedules its timeout.
- `series` waits till callback is called 400ms later, then adds the result and exits due to error. (result is now `["One", "Two", undefined]`)
- the fourth task is never executed, and its timeout is never scheduled.

The fact that you got the same result is due to the fact that you rely on `setTimeout` in your tasks.

As to how to use `parallel` usefully, try to download a hundred web pages with `parallel`; then do the same with `series`. See what happens.

Comment: So the main callback is always at last, right? How can i use async.parallel usefully, so that i can see the difference between async.parallel and async.series.

Comment: Main callback is what you have commented as "optional callback" in your code

Comment: @user1743843: Sorry, took a while till I wrote out everything. :)

Answer (score 9):

As you can see in the documentation:

- For async.series :

> Run an array of functions in series, each one running once the previous function has completed.

that's mean that async will wait that the "n" function ends before call the "n+1".

- For async.parallel

> Run an array of functions in parallel, without waiting until the previous function has completed.

But your piece of code is too simple to see the difference.
If both of them work for you you should choose async.parallel it is faster.

Comment: please show me some samples code about async.series and async.parallel. i try this https://gist.github.com/kostonstyle/6087488, the performance is pretty the same.

Comment: For me, it seems like that async.parallel use process.nextTick concept. It is so difficult to imagine, when i don't have an sample.